# How to hide table definition in ssrs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

In a report I have full forms and created text boxes for them. How do I make it visible for only who click  on it ?

```
Index 
     1. ASAP - As soon as possible 
     2. CCMS - Certificate Candidate  Management  System 

and 20 more all put in a text box
```

How do I make the contents of index visible only when toggled on index without using tablix as I have no visibility expression

Comment: How can you click something that is not visible? Maybe you should include a picture or something for better understanding

Comment: I "think" the OP is saying that the report is made up entirely of textboxes and wants the user to be able to click the *index* textbox and this will toggle visibility on the 20 or so textboxes below it. There is no tablix rowgroup to expand/collapse. ASs I said, I think that's what they are asking...